# fixing error out of stack space in worksheet_ selection change

Tags: excel, vba

i have this code  works  very well  in worksheet change  but  when  i  put  the  code  into  selection event  it  gives  me  error out of stack space  and  close  the  file  i  would  when  i  delete  the comment  in some cell   and   move   another cell  then  the  cell become none color  and  if  the  cell none  color  and  insert  comment  then move  another cell should  highlight by red

```
Private Sub Worksheet_selectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim r As Range, cmt As Range, cel As Range, NewRange As Range
Dim ar()

Set r = Range("A1", Range("h" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
On Error Resume Next
Set cmt = r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments)
r.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
For Each cel In r
If Intersect(cel, cmt) Is Nothing And cel.Value > 0 Then
    If NewRange Is Nothing Then
        Set NewRange = cel
    Else
        Set NewRange = Union(NewRange, cel)
    End If
End If

Next cel
NewRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
End Sub
```

thanks in advance

Comment: hi, BigBen  just  add selection_ change instead of  change   anyway  i  edited  my  code

Comment: Can't reproduce. Do you have any lines of code that are `Select`ing? Try toggling events off with `Application.EnableEvents = False` and `Application.EnableEvents = True` at the end. Note that the blanket `On Error Resume Next` is not proper error handling.

Comment: yes, works  in  one  case   when  insert  comment  colored by red  but  when  i   delete  it  gives  me  run time  error 1004   no cells  were found in this  line                                       Set cmt = r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments)